# Jquery: add custom row in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I created an html page, which contains five columns. The last one contains a button. (Each row has a button in the last column).

I'm using datatables plugin:

```
var oTable = $(".datatable-fn").dataTable({
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
});
```

Now I need to add new row to the tables. I know that exists [`fnAddData`](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/add_row.html) function that do this, but I don't know how can I add the button in the last cell of the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any HTML content in the new cells:

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    giCount+".1",
    giCount+".2",
    giCount+".3",
    "<button>My button</button>" ] );
```

Using [createElement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp):

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "My button";

$('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    giCount+".1",
    giCount+".2",
    giCount+".3",
    button.outerHTML  ] )
```

Comment: So simple? :D Can I define a more complex object, using createElement, and then pass the object to the fnAddData?