# Add custom elements in DataTable rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add an element before each row of table in this way:

```
 $('tbody tr').each (function(){
     var htm =$(this).html();
     var tdm = "<td><button>Add</button></td>" ; 
     $(this).html(tdm+htm);
     });
```

but when I add an element with jquery first it appears and then it quickly disappears. Probably datatables has a mechanism to remove external element injections. A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601356/jquery-add-custom-row-in-datatables) but doesn't work. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is the datatables initialization code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table =  $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "?r=group/subscribe",

        "columns": [

            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "uid" },
            { "data": "first_name" }
        ], 
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
        } ],
    initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select ><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
```

**UPDATE:**
Answered by @Bala Sakthis, now the buttons appear but not before the rows, rather  a new row is created for every button before the table. This information might be helpful!
[image: sample after Bala Sathis's Answer]

Comment: What version of DataTables are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10.7

Comment: You need to use jQuery DataTables API or options, for example [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). Show your DataTables initialization code so we could help you.

Comment: added the initialization code in the question. Kindly Check

Comment: @RameshPareek, do you want to add a Dropdown in a specific column?

Comment: @Bala Sakthis I want to be able to prepend to every row any html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer the below code for adding a `Button` (in all the rows) in one of the Columns:

```
{
    "data": "Status",
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return $('<button>')
                        .attr('class', 'btn btn-danger')
                        .text('Add')
                        .wrap('<div></div>')
                        .parent()
                        .html();
    }
}
```

The Logic for Button Click Event can be written here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
        // Add Logic for Button Click Event
    });
});
```

And check the below link for adding buttons in the Table `HEADER`.
http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/3914/adding-buttons-to-header-or-footer

Please check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bala_sakthis/3fLhkLxm/) for the updated code.

Comment: half of the job done! :) this creates buttons but the buttons are created in new rows, these rows contain only the buttons and the rest of the rows follow

Comment: @RameshPareek, I guess you meant columns and not rows. You can add the render portion of the code to all the columns wherever you need a button. I have a sample code for adding a hyperlink also.

Comment: I mentioned rows :), but please see the picture after applying your solution, they are appearing before rows only, not columns

Comment: @RameshPareek, Can you please post a screenshot of how you need the button?

Comment: see the screenshot above, the buttons are in separate rows, above the actual rows. I need them in front of their respective rows.

Comment: above code generates an 'unknown parameter' error. the error message refers to http://datatables.net/tn/4  error. The possible reason is that I have only three attributes in my data, while we are trying to display 4 columns. Kindly refer to the above link, may be we can reach some solution.

Comment: @RameshPareek, yes. then you have to remove the 4th column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102235/discussion-between-ramesh-pareek-and-bala-sakthis).

Comment: if you think the question also is helpful for the community, you may consider an upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to add a cell that wasn't there in the first instance?

```
"columns": [
    {
        "title": "Button",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return $('<button></button>',{
                'class', 'btn btn-danger',
                'text': 'Add'
            }).prop("outerHTML");
        }
    },{ 
        "data": "id" 
    },{ 
        "data": "uid" 
    },{ 
        "data": "first_name" 
    }
]
```

If you replace your `columns` array with this and get rid of the `columnDefs` and `initComplete` does this work for you?

Comment: trying your code, in the function, I think the ['class', 'btn btn-danger'] should be replaced with [class:'btn btn-danger' ].  so changed it, but it throws a nasty datatables error, :)  says : cannot read property 'style' of undefined. which refers to some datatables'  'inside jargon'.

Comment: That's an interesting stylistic choice as according to the JSON specification JSON is effectively made up of key:value pairs with the key being a [string](http://www.json.org/). Generally speaking I use double quotes rather than single quotes though. Javascript is generally forgiving and will usually accept unquoted strings as the key... though I'm, pretty sure that `class` is a reserved [word](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) so it's probably better to quote it. If you replace the quotes does it do what you want?

Comment: no, it  throws an error as I said. cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: @RameshPareek, 'class', 'btn btn-danger' refers to the CSS Class for the button. The CSS for 'btn btn-danger' will be present in the Bootstrap CSS. I guess, your project doesn't use Bootstrap.

Comment: @RameshPareek, I have added the JSFiddle Link in the answer. Please check and accept.

Comment: How can I know if it was the right question or not? :)